# Adding cells to visible empty UITableView show up with white background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using Xcode 10+, Swift 4+, iOS 11+

I've created a simple Search View that has a SearchBar at the top,
with a UITableView beneath.

When the view is first displayed, the Table is empty, and as the user enters text into the search bar, I add results to the table. Functionally, everything works ok.

Next, I've made the main View background blue and want the entire TableView to be clear so I can see the background.

I've set the table view background in the "viewDidLoad" :

```
myTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

In "cellForRowAt" I set the cell background to clear:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

However, when the search returns values and cells are added to the table,
they always have a white background instead of clear.

If I pop and then push the Search View without clearing the table, the existing table cells show up (redraw) the way I want them - clear.

I've also tried adding this to "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" but it does not help:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

How can I make the cells show clear when they are first created?

Comment: When you look at the view heirarchy debugger, what exactly is white?

Comment: @Mocha I looked into the hierarchy and saw the problem - I was using the SearchBar Controller instead of just the SearchBar - so I had two TableViews appearing in the hierarchy and the one belonging to the Search was the issue.  I have now changed to the Search Bar (only) and it's working. Thanks, and DUH!

Answer (score 0):

try to set cell or tableView backgroundColor when cell will dispaly.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

or you can override function `setBackgroundView` to debug problem.